How to set EEE to tg3 driver so it would be enabled and active
I tried multiple things to have it enabled (via BIOS, kernel boot parameters, etc.).  I'm using HP ML350p gen8 server.
I managed to have it enabled but now I have it in status (eno1 is connected, eno2 not):
ethtool --show-eee eno1
EEE settings for eno1:
    EEE status: enabled - inactive
    Tx LPI: 2047 (us)
    Supported EEE link modes:  100baseT/Full
                               1000baseT/Full
    Advertised EEE link modes:  100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised EEE link modes:  Not reported


Same status goes for eno2, eno3, eno4 even when disconnected.
For example eno2:
ethtool --show-eee eno2
EEE settings for eno2:
    EEE status: enabled - inactive
    Tx LPI: 2047 (us)
    Supported EEE link modes:  100baseT/Full
                               1000baseT/Full
    Advertised EEE link modes:  100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised EEE link modes:  Not reported

Questions:

why is it inactive (EEE status: enabled - inactive) on every single interface (it does not matter if it is connected or not)?
what influences the inactive status?

Here is dmesg output for tg3 (see last line):
[   12.188581] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(N/A) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address 9c:8e:99:63:a6:c8
[   12.188590] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   12.188594] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[   12.188597] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   12.436319] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eth1: Tigon3 [partno(N/A) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address 9c:8e:99:63:a6:c9
[   12.436325] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eth1: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   12.436328] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eth1: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[   12.436331] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eth1: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   12.475603] tg3 0000:02:00.2 eth2: Tigon3 [partno(N/A) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address 9c:8e:99:63:a6:ca
[   12.475610] tg3 0000:02:00.2 eth2: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   12.475612] tg3 0000:02:00.2 eth2: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[   12.475615] tg3 0000:02:00.2 eth2: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   12.580959] tg3 0000:02:00.3 eth3: Tigon3 [partno(N/A) rev 5719001] (PCI Express) MAC address 9c:8e:99:63:a6:cb
[   12.580964] tg3 0000:02:00.3 eth3: attached PHY is 5719C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   12.580966] tg3 0000:02:00.3 eth3: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[   12.580968] tg3 0000:02:00.3 eth3: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   12.686953] tg3 0000:02:00.2 eno3: renamed from eth2
[   12.711083] tg3 0000:02:00.1 eno2: renamed from eth1
[   12.810853] tg3 0000:02:00.3 eno4: renamed from eth3
[   12.843066] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   16.622083] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   16.622096] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[   16.622099] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: EEE is disabled

